# Replicacion de oracle 12c a postgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Hola amigos estoy tratando de replicar datos de una base de datos de `oracle` a una base de datos de `postgreSQL` , investigando he dado con la aplicación `oracle golden gate`.

El punto es que estoy trabajando con dos maquinas virtuales en una tengo instalado el `oracle DB` y en la otra `PostgreSQL` , la duda que tengo es ¿cuál golden gate debo de instalar para cada maquina virtual?.

En la pagina oficial de oracle aparecen:

- el golden gate de oracle a oracle
- y el de oracle a postgresSQL

pero no se cual instalar en cada maquina virtual.

Se los agradeceria si alguien me da una idea de como se hace.

Comment: Cada SGBD tiene que tener instalado su propio GoldenGate. Lo único que tienes que mirar es el sistema operativo y el tipo de SGBD que estás usando. No entiendo cuál es el problema.

Comment: Gracias por lo que te entiendo , en la maquina virtual donde tengo instalado oracle 12c debo de instalar el golden gate de ¨para oracle¨ checando el correspondiente S.O y en la maquina Virtual donde tengo instalado el PostgreSQL9.5.0 tengo que instalar el golden gate para postgres.. Gracias por tu respuesta es la primera vez que trabajo en replicaciones. Saludos

Comment: Si has solucionado por ti mismo el problema, estaría bien que publicaras tú mismo una respuesta con la información y la aceptaras. Esto ayudará a futuros visitantes del sitio.

Comment: comparto la idea de @Konamiman. Saludos